# Java-8 Sort List of objects concerning inner object

Tags: list, sorting, java-8

I have a List of obejcts which looks like this:

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = ...
```

and MyObject has a reference to another object MyReferencedObject. 
I will sort List myObjects concerning a field of MyReferencedObject called sortOrder (Integer).
Is there a performant possibility to do this in a performant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either make it implement `Comparable` (especially if such comparison is not one-off and will be reused).

Then just call:

```
Collections.sort(myObjects);
```

Or define the order using a lambda expression:

```
Collections.sort(myObjects, (o1, o2) ->
      o1.getReferencedObject().getSortOrder()
      .compareTo(o2.getReferencedObject().getSortOrder()));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second solution works for me (MyObject is compareable by another field). Thanks!

Comment: You can also use Comparator::comparing to derive a Comparator from a getter Function: Collections.sort(myObjects, Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getReferencedObject().getSortOrder()));